# What is the difference between Super User and Web Application Stack Exchange 'groups'?

Tags: discussion, scope, migrated-questions, superuser

How come the following question was migrated from *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)* to the *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site?

*[How to generate a YouTube playlist of the most recent videos from each channel you follow?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150442/how-to-generate-a-youtube-playlist-of-the-most-recent-videos-from-each-channel-y)*

but then when I created this question, it was migrated back to Super User?

*[How to prevent Chrome from creating a nested folder when bookmarking all opened tabs into a specific folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1621305/how-to-prevent-chrome-from-creating-a-nested-folder-when-bookmarking-all-opened)*

Both questions are related to dealing with applications, one is a browser and the other is a website, but can that not also be considered an application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) handles "question about computer software or hardware", while [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) handles "question about web applications".

When it is about browsers handling websites/web apps, a simple litmus test:

- If it is about operating browsers that are independent of the web sites, then it is most likely more suitable on Super User.
- If it is about operating web apps that are independent of the browsers, then it is most likely more suitable on Web Applications.

---

For this specific case,

- "How to prevent Chrome from creating a nested folder when bookmarking all opened tabs into a specific folder?" is a Chrome-specific question, but independent of web sites of the opened tabs
- "How to generate a YouTube playlist of the most recent videos from each channel you follow?" is a YouTube-specific question, but independent of the browsers.

Comment: These have been more separated, but not anymore, maybe it's time to merge those 2 portals together?

Comment: @jave.web well, you can ask each community on their meta site whether they want to be merged or not...

Comment: there are more meta stack exchange sites ?   Are they like this for all the sites? Hmmm, I think I will fallback here, Super User seems more complex "Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking"...